# Bootstrap Carousel, loop every two items

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I'm trying to get the carousel to show two items per slide in every loop which isn't working at the moment, here is the code that I have:-

```
<div id="hot-jobs-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <?php
        if ($x == 0) {
        echo '<li data-target="#hot-jobs-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>';
        } else {
        echo '<li data-target="#hot-jobs-carousel" data-slide-to="'.$x.'"></li>';
        }
    ?>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

    <?php if ($x == 0 || $x == 1) { ?>

        <div class="item active">

            <div class="col-md-12 row">

                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                    <div class="<?php echo $job_sector_html; ?>-wrapper sector-wrapper">
                        <p class="job-sector"><span id="icon-<?php echo $job_sector_html; ?>" class="icon-sector-sm"></span><?php the_field('job_sector'); ?></p>
                        <p class="job-title"><?php echo get_the_title( $ID ); ?></p>
                        <p class="job-attributes"><?php echo get_field('job_location') . ' | ' . get_field('job_type') . ' | ' . $job_salary; ?></p>
                        <div class="view-job <?php echo $job_sector_html; ?>-bg">View<br>this job</div> 
                    </div> 
                </a>

            </div>

        </div>

        <?php } ?>

        <?php if ($x == 2 || $x == 3) { ?>

        <div class="item">

            <div class="col-md-12 row">

                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                    <div class="<?php echo $job_sector_html; ?>-wrapper sector-wrapper">
                        <p class="job-sector"><span id="icon-<?php echo $job_sector_html; ?>" class="icon-sector-sm"></span><?php the_field('job_sector'); ?></p>
                        <p class="job-title"><?php echo get_the_title( $ID ); ?></p>
                        <p class="job-attributes"><?php echo get_field('job_location') . ' | ' . get_field('job_type') . ' | ' . $job_salary; ?></p>
                        <div class="view-job <?php echo $job_sector_html; ?>-bg">View<br>this job</div> 
                    </div> 
                </a>

            </div>

        </div>

        <?php } ?>

    </div>

    <?php $x++; endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#hot-jobs-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#hot-jobs-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>

</div>
```

At the moment it is just displaying as follows and not scrolling:-

[image]

Also, at the moment there are only 4 items, where as it could have 20 items+, how could I adapt my code so it only shows two items at a time without having to specify the ones I want to display (replacing: )

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you initialize the carousel using `$('.carousel').carousel()`?

Comment: ^ yes, that's already done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solve the problem with the below simplified code:-

```
<?php if($job_increment==0 || $job_increment%2==0 ){ echo '<div class="item '.(($job_increment==0)?'active':'').'">'; } ?>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="<?php echo $job_sector_html; ?>-wrapper sector-wrapper">
                    <p class="job-sector"><span id="icon-<?php echo $job_sector_html; ?>" class="icon-sector-sm"></span><?php the_field('job_sector'); ?></p>
                    <p class="job-title"><?php the_title( $ID ); ?></p>
                    <p class="job-attributes"><?php echo get_field('job_location') . ' | ' . get_field('job_type') . ' | ' . $job_salary; ?></p>
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"><div class="view-job <?php echo $job_sector_html; ?>-bg">View<br>this job</div></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php echo ($job_increment%2!=0)?'</div>':''; ?>
<?php $job_increment++; endwhile; ?>
```

Note: changed $x to $job_sector;

Answer (score 0):

You have a div inside your item with both the class row and the class col-md-12, but the column needs to be inside a row, which could help

Try this :

```
<div class="item active">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
            <div class="<?php echo $job_sector_html; ?>-wrapper sector-wrapper">
            <p class="job-sector"><span id="icon-<?php echo $job_sector_html; ?>" class="icon-sector-sm"></span><?php the_field('job_sector'); ?></p>
            <p class="job-title"><?php echo get_the_title( $ID ); ?></p>
            <p class="job-attributes"><?php echo get_field('job_location') . ' | ' . get_field('job_type') . ' | ' . $job_salary; ?></p>
            <div class="view-job <?php echo $job_sector_html; ?>-bg">View<br>this job</div> 
        </div> 
        </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<?php if ($x == 2 || $x == 3) { ?>

<div class="item">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
                <div class="<?php echo $job_sector_html; ?>-wrapper sector-wrapper">
                    <p class="job-sector"><span id="icon-<?php echo $job_sector_html; ?>" class="icon-sector-sm"></span><?php the_field('job_sector'); ?></p>
                    <p class="job-title"><?php echo get_the_title( $ID ); ?></p>
                    <p class="job-attributes"><?php echo get_field('job_location') . ' | ' . get_field('job_type') . ' | ' . $job_salary; ?></p>
                    <div class="view-job <?php echo $job_sector_html; ?>-bg">View<br>this job</div> 
                </div> 
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```